# Moodle: Using SQL IN operator in $DB->get_records_sql

Tags: moodle

I can't seem to get the SQL IN operator to work with the correct moodle way of inputting variables into the sql string.

When I do this:

```
$activities = '('.$section->sequence.')';



$sql = "SELECT assign.name FROM {assign} assign

        INNER JOIN {course_modules} cm

            ON cm.instance = assign.id

        INNER JOIN {modules} m

            ON m.id = cm.module

        WHERE m.name = 'assign' AND

            cm.id IN ?";

$assignments = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array($activities));
```

it doesn't work, it says there is an error in my sql syntax around the IN operator.

But when I do it this way, it works. (Not using the ?)

```
$sql = "SELECT assign.name FROM {assign} assign

        INNER JOIN {course_modules} cm

            ON cm.instance = assign.id

        INNER JOIN {modules} m

            ON m.id = cm.module

        WHERE m.name = 'assign' AND

            cm.id IN ".$activities;



$assignments = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, null);
```

How can I get it to work using the correct moodle syntax. ie. `$assignments = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array($activities));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has been answered in the Moodle forums: https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=328597